# Cannot start MySQL in MAP (Mac)

Tags: mysql, git, macos, mamp

I installed MAMP on my Mac (OS Sierra 10.12.1) and it worked fine. I am developing Moodle with Eclipse and use GIt too. I couldn't start MySQL after few days and I thought it is due to some issues in MySQL server.

I reinstalled MAMP and worked fine again. Now, I got the same issue and cannot start MySQL. I think there is a relation with GIT since I deleted or altered some repositories. I have copied the MySQL error report.

I tried suggestions like Kill MySql processors but didn't help.

> 161216 10:37:23 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.33) starting as process 6013 ...
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 7705227 in the ib_logfiles!
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>   2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
>   2016-12-16 10:37:23 6013 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace moodle/mdl_config_plugins uses space ID: 2 at filepath: ./moodle/mdl_config_plugins.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd
>
> 2016-12-16 10:37:23 7fffe235b3c0  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
>
> InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
>   InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
>   InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
>   InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file  ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd
>   InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
>   InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
>   InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
>   InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
>   InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
>   InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
>   InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
>   InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
>   InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
>   InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
>   InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
>   161216 10:37:23 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file   /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem with help of many posts. 
1) stop Mamp 
2) create my.cnf file in Applications/MAMP/Conf folder  
3) paste this content 
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
innodb
innodb_force_recovery = 1 
5) restart MAMP   
now Sqlserver  started 
6) I commented all lines using # (may be step 6 is not necessary)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with help of many posts.

1) stop MAMP

2) create my.cnf file in Applications/MAMP/Conf folder

3) paste this content

[mysqld]

default-storage-engine = InnoDB

innodb

innodb_force_recovery = 1

5) restart MAMP
now Sqlserver  started

6) Then, I got the error "cannot write database" when I run the web application, Then I did the 7 step and solved.

7) I commented all lines using #

Comment: What is "the 7 step" ?